# Pre and Postfix Increment

Tags: java, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

```java
a = 1;
int a2 = a++;
System.out.println("----------Test 3 ----------");
System.out.println("The value of a is " + a);
System.out.println("The value of a2 is " + a2);
System.out.println("The value of a2 is " + a2);
```

The result is :

> ----------Test 3 ----------
>
> The value of a is 3
>
> The value of a2 is 2
>
> The value of a2 is 2

I don't understand why the value of `a2` does not increase after the second output. Even `a` is increased using postfix increment and assigned to `a2`. Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why the value of a2 does not increase after the
> second output even a is increased using postfix increment and assigned
> to a2.

Let us go step by step:

```
a = 1
```

set the variable `a` to 1; Now:

```
int a2 = a++;
```

will be equivalent to:

```
int a2 = a;
a++;
```

first assigned and only then increment, hence the output:

```
The value of a is 2
The value of a2 is 1
The value of a2 is 1
```

and the name **post**fix increment.

For the behavior that you want use `++a` instead, namely:

```
int a = 1;
int a2 = ++a;
System.out.println("The value of a is " + a);
System.out.println("The value of a2 is " + a2);
System.out.println("The value of a2 is " + a2);
```

Output:

```
The value of a is 2
The value of a2 is 2
The value of a2 is 2
```

In this case :

`int a2 = ++a;` is equivalent to :

```
 a++;
 int a2 = a;
```

Answer (score 1):

The prefix and postfix increment only matter within the statement you are executing.  Try adding prefix and postfix increments in the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

that is how the post increment operator is designed to work...

doing

```
int a2 = a++;
```

is equivalent to doing

```
int a2 = a;
a = a + 1;
```

so your code is producing this output:

```
----------Test 3 ----------
The value of a is 2
The value of a2 is 1
The value of a2 is 1
```